# Why are start constraints being generated when I update the schedule?

Tags: ms-project, constraints

When I update MS Project for the current date, the program is generating start constraints on activities that have not started yet. These activities do not need to start at the update Date, but can start later based on the logic and available Slack.

Why is it creating a start constraint and not allowing the activity to move forward to the current date if it has not started? How do I get the program to stop creating "constraints"?

Comment: If your activity is set to Automatic scheduling then Project will try to set it to start at the earliest based on available dependencies and constraints. The result however may be in the past, so you are probably seeing tasks that are set to start, say, 2 months ago. If you need them to start at a specific point in time set a "Start no earlier than" constraint, otherwise set the proper predecessors so that Project calculates it for you.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the Update Project dialog will impose a SNET constraint on all activities whose current start dates precede the selected update date.  You can reduce the number of superfluous constraints by repeating the the Update Project dialog only on selected tasks.